# How to properly use DynamoDB in a Docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-dynamodb, containers, boto3

I am new to Docker and trying to figure out how to use dynamodb and boto3 within my Docker image. I have followed many tutorial and read many articles. From what I have the basic setup of most dockerized applications have a docker-compose file with two images, the service you have built, and an image of the database. So here is where I am confused, the only image I can find of DynamoDB is dynamodb-local. And to my understanding this image is only used to create a localized database on your computer. I need the ability to connect to an actual dynamodb table on my aws account. I currently just have instructions in my Dockerfile to download boto3 on build. Just wondering if I am doing anything wrong? Could anyone give some clarity, or some good resources to read?

Answer (score 2):

If you need to connect to an external DynamoDB instance then you don't have to create a container for it.

You can just pass the required credentials to access the AWS hosted instance through environment variables to the other service container.

Although I do recommend spinning up a local database for development purposes.